# Remove Wordpress Menu Classes and ID with Bootstrap Walker

Tags: menus, navigation, walker, twitter-bootstrap

How to remove generated WordPress menu `classes` and `id` and only keep the Bootstrap recommended ones without affecting the functionality of the Navbar.

I found this code which looks good and I've commented on the `ids` part but the `classes` are still showing up as `menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page nav-item` I wanna keep only the `nav-item` part only. Another issue is when the item has a dropdown menu it floats on top of another item as shown in the screenshot

[image: Menu Look]

```
if ( ! class_exists( 'WP_Bootstrap_Navwalker' ) ) :
    /**
     * WP_Bootstrap_Navwalker class.
     */
    class WP_Bootstrap_Navwalker extends Walker_Nav_Menu {

        /**
         * Whether the items_wrap contains schema microdata or not.
         *
         * @since 4.2.0
         * @var boolean
         */
        private $has_schema = false;

        /**
         * Ensure the items_wrap argument contains microdata.
         *
         * @since 4.2.0
         */
        public function __construct() {
            if ( ! has_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_args', array( $this, 'add_schema_to_navbar_ul' ) ) ) {
                add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_args', array( $this, 'add_schema_to_navbar_ul' ) );
            }
        }

        /**
         * Starts the list before the elements are added.
         *
         * @since WP 3.0.0
         *
         * @see Walker_Nav_Menu::start_lvl()
         *
         * @param string           $output Used to append additional content (passed by reference).
         * @param int              $depth  Depth of menu item. Used for padding.
         * @param WP_Nav_Menu_Args $args   An object of wp_nav_menu() arguments.
         */
        public function start_lvl( &$output, $depth = 0, $args = null ) {
            if ( isset( $args->item_spacing ) && 'discard' === $args->item_spacing ) {
                $t = '';
                $n = '';
            } else {
                $t = "\t";
                $n = "\n";
            }
            $indent = str_repeat( $t, $depth );

            // Default class to add to the file.
            $classes = array( 'dropdown-menu' );
            
            /**
             * Filters the CSS class(es) applied to a menu list element.
             *
             * @since WP 4.8.0
             *
             * @param array    $classes The CSS classes that are applied to the menu `<ul>` element.
             * @param stdClass $args    An object of `wp_nav_menu()` arguments.
             * @param int      $depth   Depth of menu item. Used for padding.
             */
            $class_names = join( ' ', apply_filters( 'nav_menu_submenu_css_class', $classes, $args, $depth ) );
            $class_names = $class_names ? ' class="' . esc_attr( $class_names ) . '"' : '';

            /*
             * The `.dropdown-menu` container needs to have a labelledby
             * attribute which points to it's trigger link.
             *
             * Form a string for the labelledby attribute from the the latest
             * link with an id that was added to the $output.
             */
            $labelledby = '';
            // Find all links with an id in the output.
            preg_match_all( '/(<a.*?id=\"|\')(.*?)\"|\'.*?>/im', $output, $matches );
            // With pointer at end of array check if we got an ID match.
            if ( end( $matches[2] ) ) {
                // Build a string to use as aria-labelledby.
                $labelledby = 'aria-labelledby="' . esc_attr( end( $matches[2] ) ) . '"';
            }
            $output .= "{$n}{$indent}<ul$class_names $labelledby>{$n}";
        }

        /**
         * Starts the element output.
         *
         * @since WP 3.0.0
         * @since WP 4.4.0 The {@see 'nav_menu_item_args'} filter was added.
         *
         * @see Walker_Nav_Menu::start_el()
         *
         * @param string           $output Used to append additional content (passed by reference).
         * @param WP_Nav_Menu_Item $item   Menu item data object.
         * @param int              $depth  Depth of menu item. Used for padding.
         * @param WP_Nav_Menu_Args $args   An object of wp_nav_menu() arguments.
         * @param int              $id     Current item ID.
         */
        public function start_el( &$output, $item, $depth = 0, $args = null, $id = 0 ) {
            if ( isset( $args->item_spacing ) && 'discard' === $args->item_spacing ) {
                $t = '';
                $n = '';
            } else {
                $t = "\t";
                $n = "\n";
            }
            $indent = ( $depth ) ? str_repeat( $t, $depth ) : '';

            if ( false !== strpos( $args->items_wrap, 'itemscope' ) && false === $this->has_schema ) {
                $this->has_schema  = true;
                $args->link_before = '<span itemprop="name">' . $args->link_before;
                $args->link_after .= '</span>';
            }

            $classes = empty( $item->classes ) ? array() : (array) $item->classes;

            // Updating the CSS classes of a menu item in the WordPress Customizer preview results in all classes defined
            // in that particular input box to come in as one big class string.
            $split_on_spaces = function ( $class ) {
                return preg_split( '/\s+/', $class );
            };
            $classes         = $this->flatten( array_map( $split_on_spaces, $classes ) );

            /*
             * Initialize some holder variables to store specially handled item
             * wrappers and icons.
             */
            $linkmod_classes = array();
            $icon_classes    = array();

            /*
             * Get an updated $classes array without linkmod or icon classes.
             *
             * NOTE: linkmod and icon class arrays are passed by reference and
             * are maybe modified before being used later in this function.
             */
            $classes = $this->separate_linkmods_and_icons_from_classes( $classes, $linkmod_classes, $icon_classes, $depth );

            // Join any icon classes plucked from $classes into a string.
            $icon_class_string = join( ' ', $icon_classes );

            /**
             * Filters the arguments for a single nav menu item.
             *
             * @since WP 4.4.0
             *
             * @param WP_Nav_Menu_Args $args  An object of wp_nav_menu() arguments.
             * @param WP_Nav_Menu_Item $item  Menu item data object.
             * @param int              $depth Depth of menu item. Used for padding.
             *
             * @var WP_Nav_Menu_Args
             */
            $args = apply_filters( 'nav_menu_item_args', $args, $item, $depth );

            // Add .dropdown or .active classes where they are needed.
            if ( $this->has_children ) {
                $classes[] = 'dropdown';
            }
            if ( in_array( 'current-menu-item', $classes, true ) || in_array( 'current-menu-parent', $classes, true ) ) {
                $classes[] = 'active';
            }

            // Add some additional default classes to the item.
            //$classes[] = 'menu-item-' . $item->ID;
            $classes[] = 'nav-item';

            // Allow filtering the classes.
            $classes = apply_filters( 'nav_menu_css_class', array_filter( $classes ), $item, $args, $depth );

            // Form a string of classes in format: class="class_names".
            $class_names = join( ' ', $classes );
            $class_names = $class_names ? ' class="' . esc_attr( $class_names ) . '"' : '';

            /**
             * Filters the ID applied to a menu item's list item element.
             *
             * @since WP 3.0.1
             * @since WP 4.1.0 The `$depth` parameter was added.
             *
             * @param string           $menu_id The ID that is applied to the menu item's `<li>` element.
             * @param WP_Nav_Menu_Item $item    The current menu item.
             * @param WP_Nav_Menu_Args $args    An object of wp_nav_menu() arguments.
             * @param int              $depth   Depth of menu item. Used for padding.
             */
            // $id = apply_filters( 'nav_menu_item_id', 'menu-item-' . $item->ID, $item, $args, $depth );
            // $id = $id ? ' id="' . esc_attr( $id ) . '"' : '';

            $output .= $indent . '<li ' . $class_names . '>';

            // Initialize array for holding the $atts for the link item.
            $atts           = array();
            $atts['title']  = ! empty( $item->attr_title ) ? $item->attr_title : '';
            $atts['target'] = ! empty( $item->target ) ? $item->target : '';
            if ( '_blank' === $item->target && empty( $item->xfn ) ) {
                $atts['rel'] = 'noopener noreferrer';
            } else {
                $atts['rel'] = ! empty( $item->xfn ) ? $item->xfn : '';
            }

            // If the item has_children add atts to <a>.
            if ( $this->has_children && 0 === $depth ) {
                $atts['href']          = '#';
                $atts['data-toggle']   = 'dropdown';
                $atts['aria-expanded'] = 'false';
                $atts['class']         = 'dropdown-toggle nav-link';
                //$atts['id']            = 'menu-item-dropdown-' . $item->ID;
            } else {
                // if ( true === $this->has_schema ) {
                //  $atts['itemprop'] = 'url';
                // }

                $atts['href'] = ! empty( $item->url ) ? $item->url : '#';
                // For items in dropdowns use .dropdown-item instead of .nav-link.
                if ( $depth > 0 ) {
                    $atts['class'] = 'dropdown-item';
                } else {
                    $atts['class'] = 'nav-link';
                }
            }

            $atts['aria-current'] = $item->current ? 'page' : '';

            // Update atts of this item based on any custom linkmod classes.
            $atts = $this->update_atts_for_linkmod_type( $atts, $linkmod_classes );

            // Allow filtering of the $atts array before using it.
            $atts = apply_filters( 'nav_menu_link_attributes', $atts, $item, $args, $depth );

            // Build a string of html containing all the atts for the item.
            $attributes = '';
            foreach ( $atts as $attr => $value ) {
                if ( ! empty( $value ) ) {
                    $value       = ( 'href' === $attr ) ? esc_url( $value ) : esc_attr( $value );
                    $attributes .= ' ' . $attr . '="' . $value . '"';
                }
            }

            // Set a typeflag to easily test if this is a linkmod or not.
            $linkmod_type = $this->get_linkmod_type( $linkmod_classes );

            // START appending the internal item contents to the output.
            $item_output = isset( $args->before ) ? $args->before : '';

            /*
             * This is the start of the internal nav item. Depending on what
             * kind of linkmod we have we may need different wrapper elements.
             */
            if ( '' !== $linkmod_type ) {
                // Is linkmod, output the required element opener.
                $item_output .= $this->linkmod_element_open( $linkmod_type, $attributes );
            } else {
                // With no link mod type set this must be a standard <a> tag.
                $item_output .= '<a' . $attributes . '>';
            }

            /*
             * Initiate empty icon var, then if we have a string containing any
             * icon classes form the icon markup with an <i> element. This is
             * output inside of the item before the $title (the link text).
             */
            $icon_html = '';
            if ( ! empty( $icon_class_string ) ) {
                // Append an <i> with the icon classes to what is output before links.
                $icon_html = '<i class="' . esc_attr( $icon_class_string ) . '" aria-hidden="true"></i> ';
            }

            /** This filter is documented in wp-includes/post-template.php */
            $title = apply_filters( 'the_title', $item->title, $item->ID );

            /**
             * Filters a menu item's title.
             *
             * @since WP 4.4.0
             *
             * @param string           $title The menu item's title.
             * @param WP_Nav_Menu_Item $item  The current menu item.
             * @param WP_Nav_Menu_Args $args  An object of wp_nav_menu() arguments.
             * @param int              $depth Depth of menu item. Used for padding.
             */
            $title = apply_filters( 'nav_menu_item_title', $title, $item, $args, $depth );

            // If the .sr-only class was set apply to the nav items text only.
            if ( in_array( 'sr-only', $linkmod_classes, true ) ) {
                $title         = $this->wrap_for_screen_reader( $title );
                $keys_to_unset = array_keys( $linkmod_classes, 'sr-only', true );
                foreach ( $keys_to_unset as $k ) {
                    unset( $linkmod_classes[ $k ] );
                }
            }

            // Put the item contents into $output.
            $item_output .= isset( $args->link_before ) ? $args->link_before . $icon_html . $title . $args->link_after : '';

            /*
             * This is the end of the internal nav item. We need to close the
             * correct element depending on the type of link or link mod.
             */
            if ( '' !== $linkmod_type ) {
                // Is linkmod, output the required closing element.
                $item_output .= $this->linkmod_element_close( $linkmod_type );
            } else {
                // With no link mod type set this must be a standard <a> tag.
                $item_output .= '</a>';
            }

            $item_output .= isset( $args->after ) ? $args->after : '';

            // END appending the internal item contents to the output.
            $output .= apply_filters( 'walker_nav_menu_start_el', $item_output, $item, $depth, $args );
        }

        /**
         * Menu fallback.
         *
         * If this function is assigned to the wp_nav_menu's fallback_cb variable
         * and a menu has not been assigned to the theme location in the WordPress
         * menu manager the function will display nothing to a non-logged in user,
         * and will add a link to the WordPress menu manager if logged in as an admin.
         *
         * @param array $args passed from the wp_nav_menu function.
         * @return string|void String when echo is false.
         */
        public static function fallback( $args ) {
            if ( ! current_user_can( 'edit_theme_options' ) ) {
                return;
            }

            // Initialize var to store fallback html.
            $fallback_output = '';

            // Menu container opening tag.
            $show_container = false;
            if ( $args['container'] ) {
                /**
                 * Filters the list of HTML tags that are valid for use as menu containers.
                 *
                 * @since WP 3.0.0
                 *
                 * @param array $tags The acceptable HTML tags for use as menu containers.
                 *                    Default is array containing 'div' and 'nav'.
                 */
                $allowed_tags = apply_filters( 'wp_nav_menu_container_allowedtags', array( 'div', 'nav' ) );
                if ( is_string( $args['container'] ) && in_array( $args['container'], $allowed_tags, true ) ) {
                    $show_container   = true;
                    $class            = $args['container_class'] ? ' class="menu-fallback-container ' . esc_attr( $args['container_class'] ) . '"' : ' class="menu-fallback-container"';
                    //$id               = $args['container_id'] ? ' id="' . esc_attr( $args['container_id'] ) . '"' : '';
                    $fallback_output .= '<' . $args['container'] . $class . '>';
                }
            }

            // The fallback menu.
            $class            = $args['menu_class'] ? ' class="menu-fallback-menu ' . esc_attr( $args['menu_class'] ) . '"' : ' class="menu-fallback-menu"';
            //$id               = $args['menu_id'] ? ' id="' . esc_attr( $args['menu_id'] ) . '"' : '';
            $fallback_output .= '<ul' . $class . '>';
            $fallback_output .= '<li class="nav-item"><a href="' . esc_url( admin_url( 'nav-menus.php' ) ) . '" class="nav-link" title="' . esc_attr__( 'Add a menu', 'wp-bootstrap-navwalker' ) . '">' . esc_html__( 'Add a menu', 'wp-bootstrap-navwalker' ) . '</a></li>';
            $fallback_output .= '</ul>';

            // Menu container closing tag.
            if ( $show_container ) {
                $fallback_output .= '</' . $args['container'] . '>';
            }

            // if $args has 'echo' key and it's true echo, otherwise return.
            if ( array_key_exists( 'echo', $args ) && $args['echo'] ) {
                // phpcs:ignore WordPress.Security.EscapeOutput.OutputNotEscaped
                echo $fallback_output;
            } else {
                return $fallback_output;
            }
        }

        /**
         * Filter to ensure the items_Wrap argument contains microdata.
         *
         * @since 4.2.0
         *
         * @param  array $args The nav instance arguments.
         * @return array $args The altered nav instance arguments.
         */
        public function add_schema_to_navbar_ul( $args ) {
            if ( isset( $args['items_wrap'] ) ) {
                $wrap = $args['items_wrap'];
                if ( strpos( $wrap, 'SiteNavigationElement' ) === false ) {
                    $args['items_wrap'] = preg_replace( '/(>).*>?\%3\$s/', ' $0', $wrap );
                }
            }
            return $args;
        }

        /**
         * Find any custom linkmod or icon classes and store in their holder
         * arrays then remove them from the main classes array.
         *
         * Supported linkmods: .disabled, .dropdown-header, .dropdown-divider, .sr-only
         * Supported iconsets: Font Awesome 4/5, Glypicons
         *
         * NOTE: This accepts the linkmod and icon arrays by reference.
         *
         * @since 4.0.0
         *
         * @param array   $classes         an array of classes currently assigned to the item.
         * @param array   $linkmod_classes an array to hold linkmod classes.
         * @param array   $icon_classes    an array to hold icon classes.
         * @param integer $depth           an integer holding current depth level.
         *
         * @return array  $classes         a maybe modified array of classnames.
         */
        private function separate_linkmods_and_icons_from_classes( $classes, &$linkmod_classes, &$icon_classes, $depth ) {
            // Loop through $classes array to find linkmod or icon classes.
            foreach ( $classes as $key => $class ) {
                /*
                 * If any special classes are found, store the class in it's
                 * holder array and and unset the item from $classes.
                 */
                if ( preg_match( '/^disabled|^sr-only/i', $class ) ) {
                    // Test for .disabled or .sr-only classes.
                    $linkmod_classes[] = $class;
                    unset( $classes[ $key ] );
                } elseif ( preg_match( '/^dropdown-header|^dropdown-divider|^dropdown-item-text/i', $class ) && $depth > 0 ) {
                    /*
                     * Test for .dropdown-header or .dropdown-divider and a
                     * depth greater than 0 - IE inside a dropdown.
                     */
                    $linkmod_classes[] = $class;
                    unset( $classes[ $key ] );
                } elseif ( preg_match( '/^fa-(\S*)?|^fa(s|r|l|b)?(\s?)?$/i', $class ) ) {
                    // Font Awesome.
                    $icon_classes[] = $class;
                    unset( $classes[ $key ] );
                } elseif ( preg_match( '/^glyphicon-(\S*)?|^glyphicon(\s?)$/i', $class ) ) {
                    // Glyphicons.
                    $icon_classes[] = $class;
                    unset( $classes[ $key ] );
                }
            }

            return $classes;
        }

        /**
         * Return a string containing a linkmod type and update $atts array
         * accordingly depending on the decided.
         *
         * @since 4.0.0
         *
         * @param array $linkmod_classes array of any link modifier classes.
         *
         * @return string                empty for default, a linkmod type string otherwise.
         */
        private function get_linkmod_type( $linkmod_classes = array() ) {
            $linkmod_type = '';
            // Loop through array of linkmod classes to handle their $atts.
            if ( ! empty( $linkmod_classes ) ) {
                foreach ( $linkmod_classes as $link_class ) {
                    if ( ! empty( $link_class ) ) {

                        // Check for special class types and set a flag for them.
                        if ( 'dropdown-header' === $link_class ) {
                            $linkmod_type = 'dropdown-header';
                        } elseif ( 'dropdown-divider' === $link_class ) {
                            $linkmod_type = 'dropdown-divider';
                        } elseif ( 'dropdown-item-text' === $link_class ) {
                            $linkmod_type = 'dropdown-item-text';
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            return $linkmod_type;
        }

        /**
         * Update the attributes of a nav item depending on the limkmod classes.
         *
         * @since 4.0.0
         *
         * @param array $atts            array of atts for the current link in nav item.
         * @param array $linkmod_classes an array of classes that modify link or nav item behaviors or displays.
         *
         * @return array                 maybe updated array of attributes for item.
         */
        private function update_atts_for_linkmod_type( $atts = array(), $linkmod_classes = array() ) {
            if ( ! empty( $linkmod_classes ) ) {
                foreach ( $linkmod_classes as $link_class ) {
                    if ( ! empty( $link_class ) ) {
                        /*
                         * Update $atts with a space and the extra classname
                         * so long as it's not a sr-only class.
                         */
                        if ( 'sr-only' !== $link_class ) {
                            $atts['class'] .= ' ' . esc_attr( $link_class );
                        }
                        // Check for special class types we need additional handling for.
                        if ( 'disabled' === $link_class ) {
                            // Convert link to '#' and unset open targets.
                            $atts['href'] = '#';
                            unset( $atts['target'] );
                        } elseif ( 'dropdown-header' === $link_class || 'dropdown-divider' === $link_class || 'dropdown-item-text' === $link_class ) {
                            // Store a type flag and unset href and target.
                            unset( $atts['href'] );
                            unset( $atts['target'] );
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            return $atts;
        }

        /**
         * Wraps the passed text in a screen reader only class.
         *
         * @since 4.0.0
         *
         * @param string $text the string of text to be wrapped in a screen reader class.
         * @return string      the string wrapped in a span with the class.
         */
        private function wrap_for_screen_reader( $text = '' ) {
            if ( $text ) {
                $text = '<span class="sr-only">' . $text . '</span>';
            }
            return $text;
        }

        /**
         * Returns the correct opening element and attributes for a linkmod.
         *
         * @since 4.0.0
         *
         * @param string $linkmod_type a sting containing a linkmod type flag.
         * @param string $attributes   a string of attributes to add to the element.
         *
         * @return string              a string with the openign tag for the element with attribibutes added.
         */
        private function linkmod_element_open( $linkmod_type, $attributes = '' ) {
            $output = '';
            if ( 'dropdown-item-text' === $linkmod_type ) {
                $output .= '<span class="dropdown-item-text"' . $attributes . '>';
            } elseif ( 'dropdown-header' === $linkmod_type ) {
                /*
                 * For a header use a span with the .h6 class instead of a real
                 * header tag so that it doesn't confuse screen readers.
                 */
                $output .= '<span class="dropdown-header h6"' . $attributes . '>';
            } elseif ( 'dropdown-divider' === $linkmod_type ) {
                // This is a divider.
                $output .= '<div class="dropdown-divider"' . $attributes . '>';
            }
            return $output;
        }

        /**
         * Return the correct closing tag for the linkmod element.
         *
         * @since 4.0.0
         *
         * @param string $linkmod_type a string containing a special linkmod type.
         *
         * @return string              a string with the closing tag for this linkmod type.
         */
        private function linkmod_element_close( $linkmod_type ) {
            $output = '';
            if ( 'dropdown-header' === $linkmod_type || 'dropdown-item-text' === $linkmod_type ) {
                /*
                 * For a header use a span with the .h6 class instead of a real
                 * header tag so that it doesn't confuse screen readers.
                 */
                $output .= '</span>';
            } elseif ( 'dropdown-divider' === $linkmod_type ) {
                // This is a divider.
                $output .= '</div>';
            }
            return $output;
        }

        /**
         * Flattens a multidimensional array to a simple array.
         *
         * @param array $array a multidimensional array.
         *
         * @return array a simple array
         */
        public function flatten( $array ) {
            $result = array();
            foreach ( $array as $element ) {
                if ( is_array( $element ) ) {
                    array_push( $result, ...$this->flatten( $element ) );
                } else {
                    $result[] = $element;
                }
            }
            return $result;
        }

    }

endif;
```

Comment: I'd recommend either using some CSS to cancel out the styles you don't want, or create the navbar yourself in `header.php`. There's not any way (that I know of) to remove classes/ids from HTML that's already been outputted to the DOM (apart from JS `.classList.remove()`, but that's not a good way of doing it here).

Comment: This is not what I'm looking for. I know a way to remove the classes and ids however it doesn't fit here due it removes everything while I need certain classes to remain